# Change MediaController icons programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, mediacontroller

How do I change `MediaController` icons programmatically? I mean *play/pause/forward and rew*.

[image]

You see I have added *fullscreen* button but can't realize how to change those three.

Custom MediaController class:

```
public class CustomVideoController extends MediaController {
public static boolean full = false;

private ImageButton fullScreenBtn;
Context mContext;
Activity activity;
VideoView mVideoView;

public CustomVideoController(Context context, Activity activity, VideoView videoView) {
    super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.VideoPlayerTheme));
    this.activity = activity;
    mContext = context;
    mVideoView = videoView;
}

@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {
    super.setAnchorView(view);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    frameParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    frameParams.setMargins(12,14,10,12);

    View v = AddFullScreenBtn();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    super.hide();
}

@Override
public void show(int timeout) {
    super.show(0);
}

private View AddFullScreenBtn() {
    fullScreenBtn = new ImageButton(mContext);
    if (full)
        fullScreenBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_stretch);
    else
        fullScreenBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_shrink);
    fullScreenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    fullScreenBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (full){
                fullScreenBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_stretch);
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                full = false;
            } else {
                fullScreenBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_shrink);
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                full = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return fullScreenBtn;
}
```

Please help me to change drawables for those icons. Is it possible at all? I'm really confused with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem recently and got a tricky way to change it.  Firstly extend the MediaController class as your customer class, then override the setAnchorView() as below. Not pretty sure if it is safe enough.

```
    public class MyMediaController extends MediaController {
    public MyMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyMediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
        super(context, useFastForward);
    }

    public MyMediaController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAnchorView(View view) {
        super.setAnchorView(view);
        //find the control buttons
        for(int index = 0; index< getChildCount(); ++index) {
            View nextChild = getChildAt(index);
            if (nextChild instanceof LinearLayout)
            {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)nextChild;
                for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 &&  linearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof LinearLayout)
                    {
                        LinearLayout linearLayoutControlPanel = (LinearLayout)linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        int len = linearLayoutControlPanel.getChildCount();
                        if (len > 0) {
                            // index = 0, pre button, just hide it
                            View buttonPre = linearLayoutControlPanel.getChildAt(0);
                            if (buttonPre instanceof ImageButton) {
                                buttonPre.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            // index = len - 1, next button, change icon to fullscreen
                            View buttonNex = linearLayoutControlPanel.getChildAt(len - 1);
                            if (buttonNex instanceof ImageButton) {
                                ((ImageButton) buttonNex).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_fullscreen));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're using `android.widget.MediaControleller`. In this case there's no way to change the layout buttons. Here's why (code bellow is from *MediaController.class*):

```
/**
     * Create the view that holds the widgets that control playback.
     * Derived classes can override this to create their own.
     * @return The controller view.
     * @hide This doesn't work as advertised
     */
    protected View makeControllerView() {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mRoot = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.media_controller, null);

        initControllerView(mRoot);

        return mRoot;
    }
```

As you can see, it's using private method to sutup and inflate its view.

Comment: @AnZ I don't think so. This is a ready-to-use widget, so there's no way to modify it like that, but you can look how it's done and implement your completely own MediaController

Comment: and if I replace icons in SDK?